# Fetch Path of a Document on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to fetch path of a document which is present at some path on iPad.
I have tried using `NSfilemanager` but these classes under `foundation framework` give me path of a document which is bundled within the application / has been written to app sandbox .

I am using one of the file explorers which shows me that a document is present on the device but i am unable to fetch the exact path of that doc on device.

**NOTE :** The document is somewhere on the device outside the application sandbox.

Thanks .

Comment: So your device is jailbroken? And what do you mean by "fetching the exact path"? If you don't know which path to use, the OS won't guess it for you...

Comment: No..device is not jailbroken..the requirement is getting path of a doc on ipad directly / thru an application.

Comment: You can not access ANY files outside your application sandbox if your device is not jailbroken.

Comment: Thanks..if it is jailbroken..how do we go about it ?

Comment: jailbreak really?...maybe look at design...i.e. possible to use iCloud or network exchange data from other sources e.g. PC or a web server..